# Favorite tags image messing up on beta sites

Tags: bug

On at least two beta sites the images for my favorite tags are messing up.

Role Playing:

[image: RPG]

Board and Card Games:

[image: BCG]

I'm running IE 8 on windows 7.

Comment: "I'm running IE 8 on windows 7.", Well there's your problem!

Comment: @Truth ie9 is currently not supported here at work so...